# Python String object does not support error

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, object, oop

**I am learning python and while i was working on this exercise...**

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores here ")

for n in range(0, len(student_scores)):
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
print(student_scores)

highest_score = max(student_scores)
print(highest_score)


**i got the below error:** 
 line 5, in <module>
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Well, what did you expect to happen *instead*? You are trying to assign a *number* in place of a *character* inside an *immutable* string.

Comment: In your own words: when the code `student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n])` runs, what do you think should happen? Show an example of exactly what you expect `student_scores` to be before and after. I can't even begin to guess what you want the overall code to do. Please read [ask] and *ask an actual question*. Tell us what problem you are trying to solve, and include a question ending in `?`.

Comment: Let's be friendly, folks! Some things about python are surprising to learners, like strings being immutable (that's not true in many languages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error says you cannot assign a string to an item. So I think what you are looking for is the function `split()`. Now say the user inputs 10 numbers split by spaces, `split()` will turn them into a list of strings. Then you can iterate through each string and turn them to ints.

```
student_scores = input("Input a list of student scores here ")
student_scores=student_scores.split()
for n in range(0, len(student_scores)): 
    student_scores[n] = int(student_scores[n]) 
    print(student_scores)

highest_score = max(student_scores) 
print(highest_score)
```

Below is a one liner of your code using list comprehension. It just looks cool so I put it here.

```
x = max([int(num) for num in input("Input a list of student scores here ").split()])
```

Comment: Note that there is no need for the list comprehension – a generator expression or ``map`` would work just as well, without creating an entire temporary list in memory. For example, ``max(map(int, input("Input a list of student scores here ").split()))``.

Comment: Actually when i run the above code, why is is printing the list values 5 times please. here is the output:                                                                                                   
  Input a list of student scores here [45, '54', '54', '78', '95', '42']
[45, 54, '54', '78', '95', '42']
[45, 54, 54, '78', '95', '42']
[45, 54, 54, 78, '95', '42']
[45, 54, 54, 78, 95, '42']
[45, 54, 54, 78, 95, 42]
95

Comment: how are you entering the numbers?